# transmute_at specified column numbers using case_when(grepl()) for multiple arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I've been searching for a solution to this issue with no luck. I have a dataframe of fish species that I need to apply a *dplyr* window function (`transmute_at`) on 27 columns of data. Data frame subset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Otherspp = c("suck SD", "BT", "SD RS", "RSS"),
  Dominantspp = c("OM", "OM", "RS", "CH"),
  Commonspp = c(" ", " ", " ", "OM"),
  Rarespp = c(" ", " ", "SD", "NP"),
  NP = rep("northern pikeminnow|NORTHERN PIKEMINNOW|np|NP|npm|NPM", 4),
  OM = rep("steelhead|STEELHEAD|rainbow trout|RAINBOW TROUT|st|ST|rb|RB|om|OM", 4),
  suck = rep("suckers|SUCKERS|sucker|SUCKER|suck|SUCK|su|SU", 4)
)
```

I need to use the columns populated with common fish codes/names (`NP`, `OM`, `suck`) to evaluate the expressions in the first four columns and output a different number, based on each of those columns, if the expression is met. So far I can only figure out how to get this to run for one column. How do I index the column name in `transmute_at` for both the new column transmute will create and the column being used to evaluate each expression.

This works for one column:

```
df <- subset(df[, c(1:4, 6)]) # using column OM for best example

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(OM = case_when(
    grepl(OM, Dominantspp) ~ "5",
    grepl(OM, Commonspp) ~ "3",
    grepl(OM, Rarespp) ~ "1",
    grepl(OM, Otherspp) ~ "1",
    TRUE ~ "0"
  )
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here is what you can do. `transmute` is similar to `mutate`. The difference is `transmute` drops other variables. `transmute_at` is a variant of `transmute`, which has three arguments. The first argument is the `tbl` or `data frame`. The second argument, `.vars`, is a place to select columns. We can use `vars(...)` to specify columns where `...` can use the same method as `dplyr::select`. The third argument, `.funs`, is the place to specidy a function to apply to all selected columns. We put the operation indise  `funs(...)`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute_at(vars(NP, OM, suck), 
               funs(Recode = case_when(
                 grepl(., Dominantspp) ~ "5",
                 grepl(., Commonspp) ~ "3",
                 grepl(., Rarespp) ~ "1",
                 grepl(., Otherspp) ~ "1",
                 TRUE ~ "0"))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   NP_Recode OM_Recode suck_Recode
#       <chr>     <chr>       <chr>
# 1         0         5           1
# 2         0         5           0
# 3         0         0           0
# 4         1         3           0
```

Or like this, without any labels after the original column names.

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute_at(vars(NP, OM, suck), 
               funs(case_when(
                 grepl(., Dominantspp) ~ "5",
                 grepl(., Commonspp) ~ "3",
                 grepl(., Rarespp) ~ "1",
                 grepl(., Otherspp) ~ "1",
                 TRUE ~ "0"))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      NP    OM  suck
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     0     5     1
# 2     0     5     0
# 3     0     0     0
# 4     1     3     0
```

Comment: how transmute_at is working here. I tried to google it,But could not find much on it. Please explain.

Comment: @PIG Thanks for your comment. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @www thanks for answering my question. I can get the reproducible example to work, but when I try to apply the code to my larger data set i get this error: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed."

Comment: Cannot help. Please compare your reproducible example and your real world datasets to see what are the differences between them.

Comment: Never mind, the code works. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad to know it works. Please accept my post as the answer if you think my post is helpful.

Comment: @www, done. Do you know how I would use this code for exact string matching instead of partial?

Comment: @ Probably by `match` (`%in%`). You may want to post a new question with a reproducible example.

Comment: @www, posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933639/transmute-new-columns-based-on-exact-match-of-multiple-words-in-string-in-r